# How to use MeshGrid method in Accord.Math Matrix Class?

Tags: c#, accord.net

I am using the Accord.Math Namespace for Visual Studio in c#.

I am trying to use the method MeshGrid<> under the Matrix class for the Accord.Math namespace. However, I am unsure how to implement this method even after reading the documentation for it seen here:
http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/M_Accord_Math_Matrix_MeshGrid__1.htm

Can anybody show me how to properly implement this method?

I have two Double[,] variables named xa and ya that I am trying to pass to MeshGrid. I have tried calling by using:

```
var q = Matrix.MeshGrid(xa,ya);
```

But for this is says that the type arguments cannot be inferred from their usage.

The output of MeshGrid is a 2-Tuple.
T1 is T[,]
T2 is T[,]

Comment: The meshgrid method in Accord.NET is analogous to MATLAB's meshgrid function. As in MATLAB, the method accepts two vectors as inputs. I fear it wont work as intended if you are passing two double[,] matrices instead of double[] vectors. Please let me know what you are trying to do exactly, as perhaps there is an easier way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The MeshGrid method in Accord.NET is analogous to MATLAB's and Octave's meshgrid functions. It can be used to help creating surface plots, [such as this one detailed in Octave's documentation page](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Three_002dDimensional-Plots.html). This method accepts two vectors as inputs, and unfortunately doesn't work if you are passing two double[,] matrices instead of double[] vectors.

If you would like to see how it works and what is the output generated by this method, perhaps we run a little snippet using the MeshGrid function in LINQPad. If you are interested, copy and paste the following LINQpad query definition in a text file and save it with a ".linq" extension:

```
<Query Kind="Program">
  <Reference>&lt;RuntimeDirectory&gt;\System.Windows.Forms.dll</Reference>
  <NuGetReference>Accord.Controls</NuGetReference>
  <NuGetReference>Accord.Math</NuGetReference>
  <Namespace>Accord.Controls</Namespace>
  <Namespace>Accord.Math</Namespace>
</Query>

void Main()
{
    double[] x = { 1, 2, 3 };
    double[] y = { 4, 5, 6 };

    var M = Matrix.MeshGrid(x, y);

    double[,] X = M.Item1;
    double[,] Y = M.Item2;

    DataGridBox.Show(X, "X");
    DataGridBox.Show(Y, "Y");
}
```

After you save this file with a ".linq" extension, double-click it to open it using LINQPad:

[image: Snippet above in LINQPad]

Once in LINQPad, execute the above snippet by hitting F5. You will get the following output windows showing the contents of the X and Y matrices, respectively:

[image: X] [image: Y]